# Codeigniter PHP Array value print in View

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have an array that holds following column values.

```
+------------+---------------+
| Subject_id | no_of_letters |
+------------+---------------+
|          1 |             5 |
|          2 |             4 |
|          3 |             6 |
|          4 |             1 |
+------------+---------------+
```

**Controller is as follows:**

```
$meta=array( 
            'UrgentLetters'=>$this->Welcome_Model->getUrgentLetters()
            );
```

**Model:**

```
function getUrgentLetters()
    {   
        $subject = $this->session->userdata('subject_id');      
        $this->db->select("letter_subject.subject_name AS subjects, count(letter_id) AS no_of_urgent");
        $this->db->from('letter_letter');
        $this->db->join('letter_subject', 'letter_subject.subject_id=letter_letter.subject');
        $this->db->join('letter_action_taken', 'letter_action_taken.ref_no=letter_letter.letter_id');
        $this->db->where('letter_letter.status=1 and letter_letter.classification=2');          
        $this->db->group_by('letter_subject.subject_name');
        $this->db->order_by('letter_subject.subject_name', 'ASC');
        $this->db->where('letter_letter.subject', $subject);
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();            
    }
```

I want to print no_of_letters of Subject_id->3. That is 6 nos. To do that I used the following code in **my view.**

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <h4><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw" style="font-size:24px;color:white"></i>
                            <span class="label label-danger" >You have <?= $UrgentLetters ?> nos of Urgent / Important Letters</span></h4>
                            </a>
```

But the code outputs `You have 1 nos of Urgent / Important Letters`.

But it should be outputting `You have 6 nos of Urgent / Important Letters`.

What might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to edit this answer based on additional information you have provided.

Add the following code right after your array $meta.

```
$UrgentLetters=$meta['UrgentLetters'][0]['no_of_letters'];
```

Comment: @ waanofii.tech. No I used getUrgentLetters() in my Model. It is working fine. The array outs Array
(
    [UrgentLetters] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Subject_id] => 3
                    [no_of_letters] => 6
                )

        )

)

Comment: @ waanofii.tech. I want to print this value (it is ->6) using my view.

Comment: @mcode Please [edit] your question to add additional information/code so that it can be formatted correctly.

Comment: @ David. I added my model to the question

Comment: try this `$urgent_letters[0][no_of_letters]`

Comment: @ KUMAR. Yes. But used as $urgent_letters[0]['no_of_letters'] instead of your $urgent_letters[0][no_of_letters]. Now working fine.

Comment: Yes. That is 6.  But now outs another message as "Undefined variable : UrgentLetters"

Comment: @mcode use this in your view `$UrgentLetters[0][no_of_letters];` & let me know what happens?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219098/discussion-between-mcode-and-kumar).

Comment: @KUMAR. Yes. I tried. The output value is 6. That is ok. But the new message as I mentioned earlier, is outs when I go any of other pages in the program

Comment: @waanofii.tech what is `['no_urgents']`?

Comment: @KUMAR That was all typing mistake i have edited the final answer and i have tested it locally on my system.

Comment: @waanofii.tech ok .

Comment: @mcode you have tried this updated answer, please let we know?

Comment: @KUMAR. I tried with your update answer. It also outs the same error. "Undefined variable : UrgentLetters".  Line Number :94. The line is "You have <span class="label label-danger" >  <?= $UrgentLetters[0]['no_of_urgent']  ?> </span>  &nbsp; nos of Urgent / Important Letters</h4>"

Comment: @mcode you use this `$UrgentLetters=$meta['UrgentLetters'][0]['no_of_letters'];`

Comment: @mcode have you succed using my updated answer? if so let us know using the triangle.

Comment: @  waanofii.tech. Yes